Convergence rate governed by a random variable
Consider a sequence of nonnegative numbers, $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, and a sequence of iid discrete random variable $\{Z_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, where $Pr[Z_n=1]=p$, $Pr[Z_n=1/2]=1-p$, with $w\in (0,1)$, satisfying,
$x_{n+1}\leq x_n Z_n$. I think $x_n$ converges to zero. Is that true?

Why do you write the $(\omega)$ for one of your random variables, and not for the other? It would be easier to understand if you used the standard capitalization, so ${X_n}$ are nonnegative random variables and ${Z_n}$ are i.i.d. with $P[Z_n=1]=w$, $P[Z_n=1/2]=1-w$ for some $w$, presumably $w \in (0,1)$ (else you can have $w=1$ and $Z_n=1$ always). I assume ${X_n}$ and ${Z_n}$ are not necessarily independent, or are they?

@Michael I am so sorry, I meant, $x_n$ is a deterministic sequence. My brain has been fried. I apologize. I have edited the question.

Oh, $x_n$ are nonnegative constants. I assume that $w \in [0,1)$ and there is a difference between $w$ and $\omega$. Now, you write your inequality $x_{n+1}\leq x_n Z_n(\omega)$ as being true, presumably, for all $\omega \in \Omega$, and since $w<1$, for all $n$ there must be some $\omega \in \Omega$ for which $Z_n(\omega)=1/2$. So it must be the case that $x_{n+1}\leq (1/2)x_n$ for all $n$.

Note that if ${x_n}$ are constants, then they either converge to zero, or they do not, it is misleading to say they converge to zero "almost surely." Also, to avoid confusion between $w$ and $\omega$ I would use $P[Z_n=1]=p$ for some $p \in (0,1)$.

@Michael Would you please look over my proof attempt and let me know where I messed up? Thank you so much for your help and patience.

@Michael I think I misunderstood your comment about almost sure convergence. So you are not saying the sequence does not converge to zero. You are saying that I should just say it converges and avoid saying almost surely converges since it is a deterministic sequence. Is that correct?

Fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be nonnegative constants. Let $\{Z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be any (possibly dependent and non-identically distributed) random variables that satisfy

$P[Z_n=1/2]>0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.
$x_{n+1}\leq x_nZ_n(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Claim: We have $0\leq x_{n+1}\leq (1/2)x_n$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.
Proof: Fix $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Since $P[Z_n=1/2]>0$, there must be an $\omega_n \in \Omega$ for which $Z_n(\omega_n)=1/2$. Then $x_{n+1}\leq x_nZ_n(\omega_n) = (1/2)x_n$. $\Box$

I finally get what you are saying now. Thank you so much.
